# Java spring data mongodb: UUID as entity ID in mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm building spring boot application with spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:

I have an etity which looks like:

```
@Document(collection = "nodes")
@Data
@Builder
public class Node {

    @Id
    UUID id;

    String info;
}
```

and repository interface:

```
public interface NodesRepository extends MongoRepository<Node, UUID> {
}
```

The problem is that when I insert Node object with empty `id` field application throws exception with the following message:

> Cannot autogenerate id of type java.util.UUID for entity of type
>   model.Node!

I know that out of box spring mongodb  supports String and BigInteger id types for autogeneration.

So I want to know is it possible to use UUID as type for my id field or not? Can I create some type of custom `MappingMongoConverter` for my entity?

Comment: may this would help you : https://craftingjava.com/tutorials/custom-document-id-spring-data-mongodb/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve this problem by creating a CustomRepository

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CustomMongoRepository<T extends BaseEntity>
    extends MongoRepository<T, Long> {
}
```

---

```
public class CustomMongoRepositoryImpl<T extends BaseEntity>
        extends SimpleMongoRepository<T, Long> implements CustomMongoRepository<T> {

    CustomMongoRepositoryImpl(
        MongoEntityInformation<T, Long> entityInformation,
        MongoOperations mongoOperations) {

        super(entityInformation, mongoOperations);
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends T> S insert(S entity) {
        generateId(entity);
        return super.insert(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends T> List<S> insert(Iterable<S> entities) { ... }

    @Override
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity) { ... }

    @Override
    public <S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities) { ... }

    protected <S extends T> void generateId(S entity) { ... }

}
```

---

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = CustomMongoRepositoryImpl.class)
public class Application {
    ...
}
```

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I would do this by implementing an `onBeforeSave` listener, or possibly an `onBeforeConvert` listener, as detailed in [the documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongodb.mapping-usage.events).

Comment: Thx, I will try this solution. The main problem is that Spring Auditing doesn't work well: if I save object in mongodb with predefined id fields, annotated with CreatedBy and CreatedDate, are null's.